# Multiple joins producing unwanted results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, group-by

I'm getting weird results from my query. The numbers are way off and I can't figure out why.

Heres the table structure for the tables used in the query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bookings` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customer_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `payment_method_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `details` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,
  `ip` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Complete',
  `booked_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booking_products` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_subtotal` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `price_total` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booking_services` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `booking_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `service_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `reservations` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `price_subtotal` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `price_total` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `payment_methods` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(191) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `payment_methods_name_unique` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Here is my query:

```
return DB::table('bookings')
    ->selectRaw('payment_methods.name, count(bookings.id) as bookings, (sum(booking_services.price_subtotal) + sum(booking_products.price_subtotal)) as subtotal')
    ->join('booking_services', 'booking_services.booking_id', '=', 'bookings.id')
    ->join('booking_products', 'booking_products.booking_id', '=', 'bookings.id')
    ->join('payment_methods', 'payment_methods.id', '=', 'bookings.payment_method_id')
    ->where('bookings.status', 'Complete')
    ->whereBetween('bookings.booked_at', [$this->carbon_from, $this->carbon_to])
    ->groupBy('payment_methods.id')
    ->orderBy('payment_methods.name')
    ->get();
```

`$this->carbon_from` and `$this->carbon_to` are carbon objects which work fine.

I'm trying to obtain the total bookings and a sum of the price_subtotals for each payment method. It seems to be grouping the booking products/services together rather than by each payment method like I want.

Am I missing something here?

Edit: here is the query log:

```
select payment_methods.name,
       count(bookings.id) as bookings,
       (sum(booking_services.price_subtotal) + sum(booking_products.price_subtotal)) as subtotal 
from `bookings` 
inner join `booking_services` on `booking_services`.`booking_id` = `bookings`.`id` 
inner join `booking_products` on `booking_products`.`booking_id` = `bookings`.`id` 
inner join `payment_methods` on `payment_methods`.`id` = `bookings`.`payment_method_id` 
where `bookings`.`status` = ? and `bookings`.`booked_at` between ? and ? 
group by `payment_methods`.`id` 
order by `payment_methods`.`name` asc
```

Comment: Can you mention exact result that you are looking for?

Comment: I did. I want the total bookings and subtotal for each payment method. Notice the joins in order to obtain the price_subtotals, that is where the problem is...

Comment: Okay. Use dd(DB::getQueryLog()) to print sql query for code you wrote. And post here.

Comment: I added it to the OP.

Comment: Wrong columm in the group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are getting cross product that is why you are getting wrong numbers for aggregation, what i suggest you, calculate your sum in individual sub clauses and then join these clauses with your main query like

```
SELECT p.name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT b.id) AS bookings,
       bs.price_subtotal + bp.price_subtotal AS subtotal
FROM bookings b
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT booking_id, SUM(price_subtotal) price_subtotal
    FROM booking_services
    GROUP BY booking_id
) bs ON b.id = bs.booking_id
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT booking_id, SUM(price_subtotal) price_subtotal
    FROM booking_products
    GROUP BY booking_id
) bp ON b.id = bp.booking_id
INNER JOIN payment_methods p ON p.id = b.payment_method_id
WHERE b.status = ? 
  AND b.booked_at BETWEEN ? AND ? 
GROUP BY p.name
ORDER BY p.name
```

I have no clue how to transform/write above query using laravel's query builder/eloquent way

Answer (score 0):

Try to group by `payment_method_id` from the `bookings` table:

```
->groupBy('bookings.payment_method_id')
```